# Master - Detail - Child in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to django, need suggestions/help, we have the following requirement, need to design html template/form using Bootstrap 5 etc.. This need to be a single page CRUD application. Is this possible in django?

**1 Master Table

1 Detail Table Foreign Key References to Master Table

1 Child Table Foreign Key References to Detail Table**

[image]

if anybody tried this type of requirement, kindly help me by providing reference articles/documents/blogs to achieve this. We have similar two applications to build, we have done application based on single table only till now, but in the above requirement we have dependent tables this is where I got struck and need help.

Tried single table forms/model/view architecture which are working fine.

Comment: Any similar examples..?